# Create a static or shared library from sycl program using dpc++

Tags: sycl, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I am trying to create a static or shared library from a sycl program and use it from a main application build using gcc/g++/clang++.
Everything is fine if I use dpcpp to build my main application, but I need to use g++.

For example, my sample sycl_lib.cpp and the main program are as follows.

```
//sycl_lib.cpp
#include<CL/sycl.hpp>
int func() {
  q.submit([&](sycl::handler &h) {
    sycl::stream os(1024, 768, h);
    h.parallel_for(32, [=](sycl::id<1> i) {
      os<<i<<"\n";
    });
  });
}

//main.cpp
void func();
int main() {
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

To create a static library and use it:

```
dpcpp -c sycl_lib.cpp -fPIC
ar rvs sycl_lib.a sycl_lib.o
dpcpp main.cpp sycl_lib.a
./a.out
```

This works fine. But I want to use g++ to build main.cpp, it is causing runtime error.

```
g++ main.cpp sycl_lib.a -L$SYSL_DIR/lib -lsycl
./a.out
```

which is giving the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cl::sycl::runtime_error'
  what():  No kernel named _ZTSZZ4funcvENKUlRN2cl4sycl7handlerEE6_12clES2_EUlNS0_2idILi1EEEE8_24 was found -46 (CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME)
Aborted
```

Is it possible for an executable created with g++ to use a sycl library created using dpc++?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer** is: while any compiler can be used for the host code, **dpcpp must be used to create the final binary (do the link) because only dpcpp knows this is a SYCL program**.

We do this by replacing:

```
$ g++ main.cpp sycl_lib.a -L$SYSL_DIR/lib -lsycl
```

with

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ dpcpp main.o sycl_lib.a -L$SYSL_DIR/lib -lsycl
```

We definitely need to document this better - sorry about that.  I'll see what we can do there (suggestions would be appreciated).

Here is why:
You can compile any host code with g++, but there is finalization required to finish the SYCL program and create the final binary (to bring together host and non-host code) that g++ knows nothing about.
dpcpp invokes “sycl-post-link” - which we get by just using dpcpp to build the final binary

Here are the files and Makefile to illustrate:

```
//main.cpp
void func();
int main() {
  func();
  return 0;
}


//sycl_lib.cpp
#include<CL/sycl.hpp>
using namespace sycl;
void func() {
  queue q;
  q.submit([&](sycl::handler &h) {
      sycl::stream os(1024, 768, h);
      h.parallel_for(32, [=](sycl::id<1> i) {
          os<<i<<"\n";
        });
    });
}


# Makefile
runG: sycl_lib.a
        g++ -c main.cpp
        dpcpp -o runG main.o sycl_lib.a -L$SYSL_DIR/lib -lsycl
        ./runG

FAILrunG: sycl_lib.a
        g++ -o runG main.cpp sycl_lib.a -L$SYSL_DIR/lib -lsycl
        ./runG

sycl_lib.a: sycl_lib.cpp
        dpcpp -c sycl_lib.cpp -fPIC
        ar rvs sycl_lib.a sycl_lib.o
        dpcpp -o runD main.cpp sycl_lib.a
        ./runD
```

**Thank you for pointing this out.**  I've added a general note to the [book errata](https://github.com/Apress/data-parallel-CPP/blob/main/book_errata.txt), and I'll talk with the dpcpp compiler documentation team about how we can document this clearly.

Comment: Dear James, That is what i was looking for.Thank you for the good explanation.

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to build a distributable shared or static library with DPC++? (As we can not impose the end user to use dpcpp to link). This seems like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

GCC is not a SYCL-aware compiler and is therefore unaware of the extra requirements needed at link time to produce an executable that works with SYCL code compiled by the oneAPI compiler (dpcpp/icx/icpx).

That does not mean that you can't use GCC though! It just means that you'll need to use the oneAPI compiler to compile SYCL source code for the target devices and to link the final executable. GCC can be used to compile non-SYCL source code as normal and can also be used to compile SYCL source code for the target host by using the oneAPI `-fsycl-host-compiler=g++` option (and maybe the `-fsycl-host-compiler-options` option as well). Please note that use of a third party host compiler such as GCC for compilation of SYCL source code introduces some language restrictions. For example, support for unnamed lambda expressions as SYCL kernels is limited. Unfortunately, I don't think these restrictions are well documented at present.

Documentation for use of a third party host compiler has been improved in recent oneAPI releases. Please see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2024-0/use-third-party-compiler-as-host-compiler-dpc-code.html for details.